# New to GCP: Deploying basic Python cloud function fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This may be a very simple question, but I'm getting persistent errors when trying to deploy a basic Python cloud function.  I created this in the main.py file.

```
def hello_http(request):
    return 'Success!'
```

Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Comment: take a look at goblet, which can help with managing and deploying your python cloudfunctions. https://github.com/anovis/goblet

Answer (score 2):

Found out that Entry Point had to be the same name as the defined function.